# AppManagementServiceApplication throws "Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process." when registering hosted app on site

Tags: sharepoint-2013, hosted-app

I'm on SP 2013 enterprise single server dev machine
I have prepped SP to host a remote on prem hosted app.
I navigate to /_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx and enter the App Id, Secret, etc and hit create ... error ID 3 and 1309 are thrown:

ID 3 is:
WebHost failed to process a request.
Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/1660113
Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/9fabc3ed921a42739ebeb5576c6b4e6a/AppMng.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable.. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft SharePoint is not supported in 32-bit process. Please verify that you are running in a 64-bit executable.

followed by 1309:
Exception information:
Exception type: ServiceActivationException
Exception message: The requested service, 'http://servername:32843/9fabc3ed921a42739ebeb5576c6b4e6a/AppMng.svc' could not be activated.

The app management and subscription services are started and running. I have a valid trust setup.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In IIS there were app pools that had enable 32-bit set to true, so I set it to false and was enable to register the app.